# Unable to solve fatal error while adding images to NSMutableArray

Tags: swift, ios8, nsmutablearray

I am trying to scroll images automatically in swift. So I am adding images in array. But, if I run, I am getting error in below line.
My Coding is below: Kindly guide me.

```
var str_1 : String = "one.jpg"
var str_2 : String = "two.jpg"
let img_1 = UIImage(named: str_1) 
let img_2 = UIImage(named: str_2)
img_arr.addObject(img_1!)//fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
img_arr.addObject(img_2!)
```

Comment: Make sure you copy the image to your Images.xcassets. Other issue might be a corrupted file or the file format is not jpg (wrong file extension)

Answer (score 0):

Delete **!** with **!** you forced unwrapping giving img_1 and img_2 nil.

```
var str_1 : String = "one.jpg"
var str_2 : String = "two.jpg"
let img_1 = UIImage(named: str_1) 
let img_2 = UIImage(named: str_2)
img_arr.addObject(img_1)//fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
img_arr.addObject(img_2)
```

Comment: Xcode is not allowing me to delete. If I delete, "Fix It - Insert "!"", this issue I am getting. @ Diego

Comment: how can i give, img_1 to be nil?

Comment: as I know with the exclamation optional you are saying that the variable is initialized with nil.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this. I got it.

```
let img_1 : UIImage = UIImage(named: str_1)!
let img_2 : UIImage = UIImage(named: str_2)!

img_arr.addObject(img_1)
img_arr.addObject(img_2)
```